# dotnet - Dealing with projects with different versions as references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference

I have a class that works today that references a project like this.

```
 MyWorkProject
   MyWorker.cs
   References
     ..\v1_0\SomeCompaniesSdk.csproj
         SdkClient.cs //version 1.0
```

I need to expand MyWorkProject and add a new `MyWorker2.cs`.  This class will add a new reference like this

```
 MyWorkProject
   MyWorker2.cs
   References
     ..\v2_0\SomeCompaniesSdk.csproj
         SdkClient.cs //version 2.0
```

I am really getting tripped up trying to import the new SomeCompaniesSdk project to use the new SdkClient.

This one has a bunch of breaking changes from the previous version so I can't just import that only, because the 1.0 version is still valid and can do things that 2.0 cannot.

How can I import another project and give it an alias like `SomeCompaniesSdkv2` so that in `MyWorker2` I could reference it like:

```
using SomeCompaniesSdkv2;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You should release version 1 and version 2 separately of each other.

Comment: Two different files in the same project need to reference different versions of an external SDK.  Both versions use the same Namespace though.

Comment: Do you have control over the SDK project? Then in this case, I'd change the namespace in there. Otherwise, this really sounds like a hard problem. Conceptually, C# APIs should be designed in a backwards compatible manner, that's how the versioning works (note that it's also not possible to include two versions of the same .nuget into a project)